# "What an idiot!" in plural form

Tags: grammatical-number

There is a phrase "What an idiot!". How should it be used for a group of people? Looks like "What idiots" doesn't have same emotional meaning.

Comment: If I was in a group of people and we were commented on as such, I don't think I'd be any the less offended than if it was a comment on me alone.

Comment: I prefer "cacophony of idiots".

Answer (score 35, accepted):

"What a bunch of idiots" works the same. Or, you can be even more offensive and say something like "what a pile of idiots," though this may not be common in some areas.

Comment: +1 I don't know why *bunch* gives the phrase a bigger punch, but you're right, it does.

Comment: If you don't mind being even more offensive, I find *shower of shit* works fine for one or several idiots.

Comment: From a linguistic point of view "a shitload of degenerate retards" would convey a similar meaning.

Comment: I like "gaggle." Perhaps "gaggle of goofuses" for those of us raised on Highlights For Children.

Comment: Certainly, *bunch* is the most common term. I've never heard *pile* but *pack* is a possibility.

Answer (score 9):

Simply saying *Idiots* would suffice. It's short, immediate, emotionally charged and relatively offensive.

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something *more* offensive, you could go with "*What imbeciles*" or "*What a bunch of imbeciles*".

Comment: +1 purely for also having *bunch*. Like you, I have no idea why *bunch* in particular is such a favoured word for these constructions. Although I do think that particulary in the past, and/or more "formal" contexts, *pack* performs a similar role.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider referring to the specific type of idiocy:

"What a bunch of lemmings" (referring to a long-disproved misconception): a group of people doing something self-destructive, apparently of their own free will.

"What a bunch of sheep": a group of people accepting exactly what they are told by someone else, without thought.

(I'm not sure why the insulting version of these phrases, and Mark's suggestions of "a bunch of idiots", uses "bunch", rather than some other collective noun, such as "a flock of sheep" or "a herd of sheep" or "a colony of lemmings").

Answer (score 1):

Indirectly related, but in the Scots dialect we have the word 'yous' (or 'youse'), which is 'you' plural - "Youse are idiots", "Youse idiots" etc. Handy for all occasions - "youse serious?" "Aye" "Youse are